# How to hide bars of one particular group in a group bar chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, lightningchart

Using LightningchartJS I have created a grouped bar chart. I have created series based upon the categories and grouped them according to the countries. Using the legend box, I can hide the bars on the basis of their series. Is there a way in which I can hide them on the basis of their groups?

```
const addGroups = (names) => { 
      for (const name of names) 
        groups.push({ 
          name, 
          tick: axisX.addCustomTick() 
          .setGridStrokeLength(0) 
          .setTextFormatter((_) => name) 
          .setMarker((marker) => marker 
                     .setBackground((background) => background 
                                    .setFillStyle(emptyFill) 
                                    .setStrokeStyle(emptyLine) 
                                   ) 
                    ) 
        }) 
    } 
    const addCategory = (entry) => { 
      // Each category has its own series. 
      const series = createSeriesForCategory(entry) 
      .setName(entry.name) 
      .setDefaultStyle(figure => figure.setFillStyle(entry.fill)) 
      entry.figures = entry.data.map((value) => series.add({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 })) 
      legendBox.add(series, 'Legend') 
      categories.push(entry) 
      redraw() 
    } 
const createSeriesForCategory = (category) => { 
      const series = chart.addRectangleSeries() 
      // Change how marker displays its information. 
      series.setResultTableFormatter((builder, series, figure) => { 
        // Find cached entry for the figure. 
        let entry = { 
          name: category.name, 
          value: category.data[category.figures.indexOf(figure)] 
        } 
        // Parse result table content from values of 'entry'. 
        return builder 
          .addRow('Department:', entry.name) 
          .addRow('# of employees:', String(entry.value)) 
      }) 
      // Apply cursor logic using series.onHover method 
      series.onHover((_, point) => { 
        if (point) { 
          const figure = point.figure 
          const dimensions = figure.getDimensionsPositionAndSize() 
          // Show band. 
          band 
            .setDimensions({ 
            x: dimensions.x - figureGap * .5, 
            y: figure.scale.y.getInnerStart(), 
            width: dimensions.width + figureGap, 
            height: figure.scale.y.getInnerInterval() 
          }) 
            .restore() 
        } else 
          band.dispose() 
      }) 
      return series 
    } 
const categories = ['Engineers', 'Sales', 'Marketing'] 
chart.addGroups(['Finland', 'Germany', 'UK'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LegendBox does have an internal concept of "groups", but it only provides grouping entries by group "tag", as well as displaying the group "tag". The group label is not interactable, so I wouldn't see it usable for this kind of purpose.

Depending on the popularity of this kind of applications, some additional capabilities to meet this need might be reasonable.

Meanwhile, a completely self-made LegendBox using UILayoutBuilders would be the other option.